# LINQ to remove certain elements from a IList<T> based on a IList<int>

Tags: c#, linq, ilist

How to use LINQ to remove certain elements from a IList based on another IList.
I need to remove records from list1 where ID is present in list2.
Below is the code sample,

```
class DTO
{

    Prop int ID,
    Prop string Name
}

IList<DTO> list1;

IList<int> list2;



foreach(var i in list2)
{
    var matchingRecord = list1.Where(x.ID == i).First();
    list1.Remove(matchingRecord);
}
```

This is how I am doing it, is there a better way to do the same.

Comment: There's no day without a similar question.

Comment: Don't use Linq for this. Linq is all about filtering and creating new sequences, not modifying collections.

Answer (score 26):

You could write a "RemoveAll()" extension method for `IList<T>` which works exactly like `List.RemoveAll()`. (This is generally useful enough to keep in a common class library.)

For example (error checking removed for clarity; you'd need to check the parameters aren't null):

```
public static class IListExt
{
    public static int RemoveAll<T>(this IList<T> list, Predicate<T> match)
    {
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (match(list[i]))
            {
                ++count;
                list.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
```

Then to remove the items from list1 as required would indeed become as simple as:

```
list1.RemoveAll(item => list2.Contains(item.ID));
```

Answer (score 16):

I would use this approach:

```
var itemsToRemove = list1.Where(x => list2.Contains(x.ID)).ToList();
foreach(var itemToRemove in itemsToRemove)
    list1.Remove(itemToRemove);
```

This approach removes the items in place. It is best used for cases where there are many items in `list1` and few in `list2`.
If the amount of items in `list1` and `list2` is similar, the approach from Cuong Le is a good alternative.

Comment: Why do a `ToList()` after the `Where`? Don't think that's needed.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Yeah, it is needed. Otherwise `itemsToRemove` iterates over `list1`. Together with the `Remove` this would yield an `InvalidOperationException`: *Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute*

Comment: Ahh, good point, forgot about that.

Comment: I downvote because your solution is really bad to me when compared with accepted answer. You make a copy of elements to remove which is absolutely not necessary. It takes more spaces and more time.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Where` for simpler:

```
list1 = list1.Where(x => !list2.Contains(x.ID))
             .ToList();
```

But you really need to remove in place, prefer @DanielHilgarth's answer

Comment: RemoveAll does not return a list, it returns an int which represents the count of items deleted.

Comment: @RobertJ. you should use RemoveAll, see my answer

Comment: It actually was in his answer before, hence my comment.

Comment: Never mind, it is an IList

Comment: @Cuong le : This is what I was looking for. I think this would work. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you recommend to use @DanielHilgarth which does not do in place remove. it do use "ToList".  You should recommend: Matthew Watson answer (accepted one).